# Redesign circuit to increase voltage to small motor

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc-motor

I have a small RC system, which is having trouble moving. I think it has to do with the motors not getting enough voltage.

The motors support up to 9 V but this is how my current situation is (3B is the battery source and it consists of three 1.5 V batteries, for a total of 4.5 V):

[image: Current Setup]

Each corner has a DC motor I think but they have 2 cables to them, one positive and a negative, so i think each motor is getting 4.5 V.

I want to increase the voltage to the motors but I’m not sure how because I don’t want to damage the receiver on the car that is also attached to the batteries in the middle (more pictures down below). I would appreciate any help.

[image: All]

[image: Pcb]

[image: Pcb]

Comment: Two motors on same caterpillar? What happens if they not equal?

Comment: Use 6 batt. in series for supplying motors but receiver part supply from batteries middle point (plus of third battery counted from gnd).

Comment: Johannes - I improved your question with some edits. Feel free to make further improvement with additional edits. As in my answer below you may get better help if you draw out the schematic of the board and add that to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [SA8302 datasheet](https://www.sytatek.com/uploads/soft/%E6%AD%A5%E8%BF%9B%E7%94%B5%E6%9C%BA%E9%A9%B1%E5%8A%A8/SA8302-Brief-V1.3.pdf) (Chinese only). On your board you might be able to cut some traces and provide a higher voltage only to the SA8302 motor driver chip. The datasheet shows that the VDD pins can take from 2 to 7 V. You definitely don't want to get the higher voltage into the smaller CPU chip.

The best method would be to carefully draw out a schematic of the complete board (by following the wiring and traces) so that you can see all the component connections. That will also show you the best way to keep the high and low voltage sections separated. There may also be some additional control that Q1 is being used for. If you can include a schematic of the board you may even receive some better design ideas.

A slightly more complex redesign may be to supply the board with 6 V (using 4 batteries) then use a simple Zener diode circuit or a 5 V low-dropout regulator to supply the CPU section with 5 V.

Note that the SA8302 motor driver is sort of a simplified version of a MX1508 motor driver.
.
.